# database sql replace statement update records

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a lot of records in postgresql database sample table s_attrs attribute like

```
sex = female, age = 32 years, disease = hepatitis B:DOID:2043
sex = male, age = 35 years, disease = hepatitis B:DOID:2043
sex = male, age = 34 years, disease = hepatitis B:DOID:2043
sex = male, age = 55 years, disease = hepatitis B:DOID:2043
sex = male, age = 37 years, disease = hepatitis B:DOID:2043
sex = female, age = 31 years, disease = hepatitis B:DOID:2043
```

I want to change it to like

```
sex="female", age="32 years", disease="hepatitis B:DOID:2043"
sex="male", age="35 years", disease="hepatitis B:DOID:2043"
sex="male", age="34 years", disease="hepatitis B:DOID:2043"
sex="male", age="55 years", disease="hepatitis B:DOID:2043"
sex="male", age="37 years", disease="hepatitis B:DOID:2043"
sex="female", age="31 years", disease="hepatitis B:DOID:2043"
```

which delete the space between the equal sign and add the quotation mark,
How can i change it. I want to use the update and replace sql, but i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have an id column in your table your base query may look like this

```
WITH attr_explode AS 
(
  SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array(s_attrs, ',')) attr
    FROM Table1 
)
SELECT id, array_to_string(array_agg(concat(trim(split_part(attr, '=', 1)), '="', trim(split_part(attr, '=', 2)), '"')), ',') s_attrs
  FROM attr_explode
 GROUP BY id
```

Output:

```
| ID |                                                     S_ATTRS |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | sex="female",age="32 years",disease="hepatitis B:DOID:2043" |
|  2 |   sex="male",age="35 years",disease="hepatitis B:DOID:2043" |
 ...
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/81b7c/13)** demo

Now to update you can do

```
WITH attr_explode AS 
(
  SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array(s_attrs, ',')) attr
    FROM Table1 
), attr_replace AS
(
  SELECT id, array_to_string(array_agg(concat(trim(split_part(attr, '=', 1)), '="', trim(split_part(attr, '=', 2)), '"')), ',') s_attrs
    FROM attr_explode
   GROUP BY id
)
UPDATE Table1 t 
   SET s_attrs = r.s_attrs
  FROM attr_replace r 
 WHERE t.id = r.id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c0fa2/1)** demo

Answer (score 1):

below  is the sample replace statement

select  replace(

replace('sex = female, age = 32 years, disease = hepatitis B:DOID:2043',' = ','="')

, ', ','",') + '"';

Answer (score 0):

do you have all that information in one column of a table?

Because if so, you may want to alter your design to have 3 columns:
Sex, age, disease.

Any way, if you want to change this, it would be something like:

```
UPDATE REPLACE(column_name, ',' , '",') FROM table_name WHERE condition;

UPDATE REPLACE(column_name, '= ' , '="') FROM table_name WHERE condition;

UPDATE CONCAT(column_name, '"' ) FROM table_name WHERE condition;
```

It would be something like this, but again, reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="sex = female, age = 32 years, disease = hepatitis B:DOID:2043";

$str=str_replace(" = ","=",$str);
//echo $str;
$str=str_replace('=','="', $str);
//echo $str;
$str=str_replace(',','",', $str);
echo $str.'"';


Find this is an Example. It may useful for your need.
```